# HttpSession is null (randomly) when retrieved from HttpServletRequest using ExternalContext

Tags: jsf, liferay, icefaces

I have following code to retrieve `HttpSession` from `HttpServletRequest` using `ExternalContext` in our `Icefaces(1.8.2) & JSF(1.2)` based Liferay environment :

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) (externalContext.getRequestMap().get("com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServletRequest");
HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
```

The above code snippet is working fluently for `Liferay 6_1_0_CE_GA1` as `httpSession` is always populated.

But, the same code in `Liferay 6_2_1_CE_GA2`, I am randomly getting `httpSession` as `null`. Couldn't figure out, what the difference can be!

I have also, tried to get `httpServletRequest` using `PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest` and then getting `httpSession` from it, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: [***Cross Posted***](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/69896568)

Answer (score 1):

When I need access to HttpServletRequest from a Liferay portlet, I have to use this:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
```

*renderRequest* is an object extended from the **PortletRequest** class. From your code, you can get the PortletRequest object this way:

```
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
```

So, the resulting code should be:

```
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest));
```

Hope this helps. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Please also try this on 6.2 GA6, which is out for a month now. In case this is a bug it might already be fixed during one of the later versions - the version you're using is almost 2 years old now.

Further, there's nothing that I'm aware of in the specification that allows access to the underlying `HttpServletRequest`. That's not to say that this is impossible (because it obviously is possible) but to say that behaviour might change, because you're outside of the specs.

I'd recommend to inspect the objects you get with a debugger and check if they're wrappers around the original servlet container's request or the actual container's objects. Also, compare if these requests are directed to the portal (check the URL) or to the portlet itself - as they're deployed in different contexts, they'll have different sessions (or one might have sessions while the other doesn't)

Comment: I am calling a utility method in `bean` using `ice:commandLink`'s action attribute. The code snippet is taken from utility method itself, which returns `null` to the caller method. I have similar code deployed in two different containers (Tomcat6) for two different liferay versions, and observing so-called different behavior.

Comment: @Olaf: Although it is not in the _portlet_ spec, at least the _servlet_ spec says about `getSession()`: _or if the request does not have a session, creates one_. So no matter where he gets the request from, it should never return `null`.

Comment: Tobias, sounds legit. What's the class of the HttpServletRequest implementation?  However, I am still waiting on a few more answers (e.g. is it fixes on GA6? Also, I am on restricted bandwidth and won't follow the cross post link currently. Might be long solved or fixed. Until I see an answer to this, I am staying quiet here...